# angularjs typeError: boolean is not a function ng-click multiple actions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

When trying to achieve this:

```
<li class="answer"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-class="answer.show[$index] ? 'selected' : ''" ng-click="(answer.Questions.length > 0) ? (answer.show[$index]=!answer.show[$index]) (setAnswer(question, answer.ID)) : setAnswer(question, answer.ID)">{{answer.Description}}</a></li>


TypeError: boolean is not a function
    at $parseFunctionCall (http://localhost/assets/scripts/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12333:15)
    at $parseTernary (http://localhost//assets/scripts/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12185:39)
    at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://localhost/assets/scripts/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js:22949:17)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost/assets/scripts/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14383:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost/assets/scripts/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14482:23)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/assets/scripts/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js:22954:23)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (http://localhost/assets/scripts/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3011:21)angular.js:11594 (anonymous function)angular.js:8544 $getangular.js:14484 $get.Scope.$applyangular.js:22954 (anonymous function)angular.js:3011 eventHandler


The problem is on my ng-click:

(answer.Questions.length > 0) ? (answer.show[$index]=!answer.show[$index]) (setAnswer(question, answer.ID)) : setAnswer(question, answer.ID)
```

How should I write this correctly?

Comment: Don't put so much logic in the View, let alone in the expression. Create a scope-exposed function in the controller and call it. `ng-click="doAllThisStuff($index)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't put so much stuff in your view if not necessary. Create a function and pass stuff you need and evaluate from there.

Also,

```
ng-click="(answer.Questions.length > 0) ? (answer.show[$index]=!answer.show[$index]) (setAnswer(question, answer.ID)) : setAnswer(question, answer.ID)"
```

this looks like a wrong ternary operation if that's what you wanted to do?

if I understand correctly:

if answer.Questions.length > 0, then (setAnswer(question, answer.ID)), if not setAnswer(question, answer.ID).

What is this part for

```
(answer.show[$index]=!answer.show[$index])
```

?

Perhaps you wanted something like

```
((answer.Questions.length > 0) && (answer.show[$index]=!answer.show[$index])) ? (setAnswer(question, answer.ID)) : setAnswer(question, answer.ID)
```